# Setting up Email notification with private message on web2py

Tags: email, notifications, message, private, web2py

I set up a website using web2py and I'm looking for help to setup an email notification that will email the the person when they get a private message. 
I already have the system able to have a semi message system/private message and I'm wondering how do I integrate that all together so that if a person gets a message, the system can automatically email that user. I been looking around to how to set it up but no luck for myself.

Thank you.

Edit: Before I start trying to integrate the messaging system, I wanted to test it out with the registration since that's the only thing I could find about web2py and email notification.

Edit2: Got the register to work and it says "email is sent". However, no actual email is sent.

This is all in the Models, menu.py. Also tried putting this in the controller, default.py.

```
auth.settings.register_next = URL('Welcome')
def Welcome():
User_Email = auth.user.email
mail.send(User_Email,'Welcome To website','Welcome To website')
if request.vars.lan == 'En':
    redirect('index',vars={'lan':'En'})
else:
    redirect('index')
#from gluon.tools import Mail
#mail = Mail()
#mail.settings. = True
#mail = auth.settings.mailer
mail = auth.settings.mailer
mail.settings.tls = False
mail.settings.server = "tls://smtp.gmail.com:587"
mail.settings.sender = "...@gmail.com"
mail.settings.login = "...@gmail.com:password"

# sends an verification e-mail upon registration
auth.settings.registration_requires_verification = True


def send_email(user, subject):
message = "" "Multi line string for %(first_name)s......"
message = open("somefile.html", "r").read()
# you also have the option to include everyone in bcc=[...]
mail.send(to=user.email,
               subject=subject,
               message=message % user)

user = db(db.auth_user).select()
for user in user:
    send_email(user, "some subject")
```

Also have in the controller/default.py

```
def login():
auth.settings.registration_requires_verification = True
auth.settings.registration_requires_approval = False
auth.settings.reset_password_requires_verification = True
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation on [sending emails](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/08/emails-and-sms#Emails-and-SMS)? If so, what have you tried, and what problems did you encounter? If the issue is how to trigger the email sending based on the receipt of a private message, it will be hard to help without knowing anything about your private messaging implementation.

Comment: I tried getting the email function to work right now, but it seems like it cannot send an email when I register. I'm only trying to set it up so it wills end an email when you register because that's the only thing I can find about how to set up web2py for email notifications.

Comment: Given that you are sending via a Gmail account, do you have `mail.settings.server = 'smtp.gmail.com:587'`?

Comment: Just put it as 'smtp.gmail.com:587' and it still gives me the error that it is unable to send the email.

Comment: Could be a security measure by Google. Have you received an email from Google to this account complaining about an insecure attempt to log in? Try `status = mail.send(...)`, and check `status.result` and `status.error` to see what response the Gmail server is sending back.

Comment: So I changed and added more code and now I am able to "send the email". It lets me register and tells me the email is sent. However, no email is actually sent.

Comment: If I use the web2py gluon.tools, it let's me register and says "email is sent", but no action happens. I'm hosting it on a public server too. I tried Yahoo as well as gmail, but both are getting me problems. I did do something and google gave me an email saying that it prevented a sign in because it didn't meet the modern security standards, but I forgot what i did as I was trying many different ways. I'm not sure what to do anything as everything I been searching up just says the same thing...

Comment: You have to `turn on` access to less secure apps. For Gmail you can do it from here https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps